# C binary tree search and count how many times a condition is happening

Tags: c, recursion, search, binary-tree

I need to go through a binary tree and count how many times a condition is happening.  I have tried to return both leaves and 1 in the same time if the condition happened else return them with 0.  Any chance for ideas?

```
int countChoose(BinTree *root) {
    if (root == NULL)
        return 0;
    updateTask(root);
    if (root->whatToDo == COUNT_MALE_ORDER) {
        if (root->gender == 'M') {
            return 1 + countChoose(root->left) +
                       countChoose(root->right);

        }
        return 0 + countChoose(root->left) +
                   countChoose(root->right);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you describe what exactly is not working? Consider putting together a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Aside: the function does not return any value when `root->whatToDo != COUNT_MALE_ORDER`

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing exactly what the problem is, it looks like the last return statement should be moved outside of the outer `if` statement, i.e.,:

```
int countChoose(BinTree *root) {
    if (root == NULL)
        return 0;
    updateTask(root);
    if (root->whatToDo == COUNT_MALE_ORDER) {
        if (root->gender == 'M') {
            return 1 + countChoose(root->left) +
                    countChoose(root->right);
        }
    }
    
    return 0 + countChoose(root->left) + countChoose(root->right);
}
```

Comment: I would simplify:  `int inc = (root->whatToDo == COUNT_MALE_ORDER) && (root->gender == 'M'); return inc + countChoose(root->left) + countChoose(root->right);`

Comment: I would too, but I am more focused on helping OP understand what the problem is, not simplifying their code.

Comment: And that's great. OP: consider it as an [improvement in the maintainability of the code](https://www.techtarget.com/whatis/definition/DRY-principle).

Comment: the return outside the if didn't fix it can you describe what Information you missing? sorry Ireally try my best!

Comment: @DorShroitman Can you start by describing exactly what is going wrong? For example, are you getting an error? If you are, then does it happen at compile-time or run-time? If your function simply returns the wrong value, then what value do you get and what value do you expect?

Comment: The code could be simplified by introducing an extra variable `int root_matches = 0;` then `if (root->whatToDo == COUNT_MALE_ORDER && root->gender == 'M') root_matches = 1;` and ending with `return root_matches + countChoose(root->left) + countChoose(root->right);`.  This also opens the way to passing a predicate function pointer to the code (`int (*predicate)(const BinTree *root)`) which evaluates whether or not the current node matches a criterion after the update (which might also become a function pointer argument too: `void (*update)(BinTree *root)`) so that the code is more general.